# Woocommerce dynamic 301 redirect

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i want to do 301 redirect from /product/%product_name% to /brands/%brand_name%/%product_name%.

What is the way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to change product url or  do you have list of products which you want to 301 redirect ?

Comment: Not, all the products

Comment: if you have already those product list then add directly that rule in .htaccess

Comment: but how can i know the brand name of the product?

Comment: how many urls you want to redirect?